# Как построить сетку при помощи flex, когда один блок занимает несколько позиций посередине

Tags: css, вёрстка, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно спозиционировать три контейнера, верxний ровом, посередине два колонками и нижний ровом. И круг абсолютным позиционированием, но как можно сделать умнее?

Comment: Это работенка для гридов

Comment: Я понимаю, но я делаю  это в реакт натив, там нет гридов

Comment: посмотрите [тут](https://reactnativeexample.com/tag/grid/), может что-нибудь найдёте